# Hovering over the arrow of the new navigation persists outside of element

Tags: bug, new-nav

[image]

As you can see it appears as if the arrow thinks it is still being hovered on while I have moved on to the new tab. This only happens when you hover over the arrow and move to the right. A few pixels further to the right of where my mouse is at in the screenshot the hover state will go away and hover the *active* tab as it should.

To make matters even worse, whenever this happens and I want to click on the tab I am actually hovering over (in this case the *active* tab) the drop-down is triggered of the arrow it believes I am hovering on (the *voted* tab)! :O

On [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com), 1.4.589.11 (Stable channel) (64-bit) Ubuntu 16.04

Also on:

- FireFox 49.0.2
- Chrome 53.0.2785.143 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Vivaldi is not in the [list of supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: Repro-ed on Chrome / Win10. It isn't clear to me what causes the focus to jump to the menu-switcher as none of the elements expand beyond their layout box. And I can't find any listeners attached to those elements either.

Comment: @DavidPostill so sad.. yet this also occurs on FireFox & Chrome (just tested)

Comment: I can repro the first bit (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 49.0.2) but **not** the "To make matters even worse" bit.

Comment: @DavidPostill I just edited that part to make it more clear, is that what you understood the first time?

Comment: @ThomasYates If I click on the arrow (to get the pull down menu) then as I move right the menu stays pulled down. It doesn't change until I hover over the first letter of the next tab. Then the pull down updates.

Comment: @DavidPostill I knew my explanation was off, I added a .gif so you can see exactly what I mean (sorry about the quality)

Comment: @ThomasYates Yes, I see that too.